# Model style for Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, database-design, models

So currently my application has a model called Vendors. I want each Vendor to have one or many owners, one or many members, and then people who track or follow the Vendor. I'm trying to decide the best layout for this and I've messed around with a few things. All of the Owners, members, and followers would also be coming from my User model. Therefore I'm thinking of making one association table with booleans as to whether the User is a follower, owner, or member.

For clarification - Owner and member would be people who work at the vendor

schema.db

```
    create_table "vendor_relationships", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.integer  "vendor_id"
        t.boolean "owner"
        t.boolean "member"
        t.boolean "follower"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
    end
```

but I'm wondering if this is the best way to go about this when it comes to speed and/or quality of code. Previously I had created separate tables for vendor_owners, vendor_members, and vendor_followers. Then I associated them with a has_many :through relationship, but I'm stuck onto which way is the best.

They would all have separate logic, or rather separate permissions as to what they were allowed to view and edit with respect to the vendor. I looking at cancan and pundit for role based authorization, but I didn't think it really applied for this situation.

A role based authorization could work if I build the schema like this

```
    create_table "vendor_relationships", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.integer  "vendor_id"
        t.string "role"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
    end
```

And then check for possible user roles against the string but I'm not sure which of these is the better option.

EDIT 1:

I'm going with the t.string "role" route, but I'm wondering how I can write the code into my model so that the associations with role = "owner" would be accessible by doing Vendor.owners... etc with Vendor.members and Vendor.followers.

This is what my code looks like currently.

```
           has_many :owners, through: :vendor_relationships,  class_name: "User", -> { where role: owner }
```

This for each variation - owners, members, followers. I've also tried using

```
          has_many :owners, through: :vendor_relationships,  class_name: "User", conditions: => ['vendor_relationship.role = "owner"']
```

but everything is giving me syntax errors here. Would appreciate some help thanks.

Comment: Do owners, members, or followers have different behavior (i.e. methods on them would need to have different logic)?

Comment: Just edited, they would have separate authorization logic if that makes sense?

Comment: Is it really many-to-many for owners/members/followers for vendors?  i.e. can a follower, follow multiple vendors in addition to a vendor having multiple followers?

Comment: Yes, they are all many to many relationships

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track.  I would do the following:

Model your owners, members, and followers all as `User`, but then give them each a role.  Start with a single role per user to keep it simple.  See: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

In the many-to-many joins table, I would remove the booleans and instead let your association handle that logic.

```
has_many :owners, through: :vendor_members, class_name: "User", conditions: {"users.role = 'owner'"}
```

Then you can just interact with owners/members/followers like so: `owners = vendor.owners`

I would also consider changing the name of the `vendor_members` table since one of the types is also members.  Maybe something like `vendor_relationships`

Comment: Would this still work if one User is say an owner on one vendor but a follower on a different vendor? For example, Say we have 2 users Bob and John and 2 Vendor's Farm1 and Farm2 would this still allow Bob to be the owner of Farm1 and a follower of Farm2?

Comment: You would have to push the "role" down into the relationship table (like your edit above suggests).  And, then update the association condition to use that instead. At that point, it's not all that different from your original booleans :)

Comment: So the association would have "self.role = 'owner'"?

Comment: Additionally that join table format hasn't worked for me, when I use conditions: it says that conditions: is not a key that can be used.